# how can i return class method result only after last call

Tags: javascript, class

```
`enter code here`
class SmartCalculator {
  constructor(initialValue) {

  this.priority = 0;
  this.decision = initialValue;

  }

  add(number) {
  this.priority = 2
  this.decision = this.decision + number
 //return this.decision 
  }

  subtract(number) {
  this.priority = 2
  }

  multiply(number) {
  this.priority = 1
  }

  devide(number) {
  this.priority = 1
  }

  pow(number) {
  this.priority = 0
  }
}
module.exports = SmartCalculator;
```

I have js class, and some test thats looks like:

```
const calculator = new SmartCalculator(1);

const value = calculator
  .add(5)
  .add(5);

assert.equal(value, 11);
});
```

If I return the result immediately after calling the add method, I get an error.
How can I return the result only after the last method  ?

Comment: Do you *know* that there will always be exactly two `.add` calls before you need the resulting value?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to chain calls to `add`, `multiply` etc, they should all return `this`. The line `calculator.add(5).add(5)` takes `calculator`, calls the leftmost `add(5)` onto it, gets the result of that (which is `6`), and tries to call `add(5)` on it. `6.add(5)` raises an error.

If you returned `this`, the leftmost call would return the updated calculator, onto which `add(5)` can be called again.

Then you need to implement a method like `getResult()` or something which returns `this->decision`, and add a call to this method after your adds: `calculator.add(5).add(5).getResult()`.

Answer (score 1):

How about changing it slightly to:

```
 const { value } = calculator
  .add(5)
  .add(5);
```

Then you just have to

```
  return this;
```

at the end of every method and add a small getter to your class:

```
 get value() { return this.decision; }
```